# git push does not respond

Tags: git, openshift

I've been using git with an openshift project for a while.  Seems that for the last couple of days I can no long push my code.  After type command, 'git push' it just hangs and does nothing.  I tried restarting the app a few times but it does not help.  Not sure if anything changed. I can see that the target is properly configured.

Comment: Sometimes it works but sometimes it doesn't? Is that correct? If so, it just sounds like a temporary network issue, nothing that has anything to do with git.

Answer (score 1):

run this command

```
rhc app show <app_name> --gears quota
```

and make sure that your gear is not out of space